# How can I get specific info depending on which project I click?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have this component that shows the projects of an user, the fact is that I want to navigate to a new component by clicking on the project name that shows info about that specific project. So I guess that I need to create one component that recieves by vue router the id of the selected project.

How can I send that project id to the new page with router link that renders that info?

Maybe sending the project id as a param?

Comment: Do you look for [dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **:parameterName** in the route object.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User }
  ]
})
```

And you can access it in your component using *this.$router.params.id*

Depending on how you want to display the information, you can either use `<router-view>` or even nested `<router-view>` to show the project details. More information can be found here

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: Thank you so much @AshTyson ! That solved all of my problems